# How to run a loop regression in r

Tags: r

I am want to run a loop regression for fund1 till fund10 based on the the LIQ-factor. I want to do this regression:

`lm(fund1S~ LIQ, data = Merge_Liq_Size)`

but for all of the funds simultaneously.

I have attached some picture of the dataset to show you the setup. The dataset has 479 observation/rows. Can anyoune help me to sturcture a code? Sorry if this question is phrased in a wrong way.

[image: dataset]

[image: dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```r
my_models <- lapply(paste0("fund", 1:10, "S ~ LIQ"), function(x) lm(as.formula(x), data = Merge_Liq_Size))
```

You can access each model by `my_models[[1]]` to `my_models[[10]]`.

Comment: Thank you! The only problem was that R thaught that every fund was named fund1s, fund2s. I have renamed the fund till fund1, fund2,..., fund10. How would you rephrase the code then?

Comment: my_models <- lapply(paste0("fund", 1:10, " ~ LIQ"),
                    function(x) lm(as.formula(x), data = Merge_Liq_Size))

?

Comment: Ah, yes. Just remove the `S` or adjust the names tothe "real" names.

Answer (score 0):

If it is `lm`, we can do this without `lapply` as well i.e. create a `matrix` as the dependent variable and construct the formula

```
lm(as.matrix(Merge_Liq_Size[paste0("fund", 1:10, "S")]) ~ LIQ, data = Merge_Liq_Size)
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
> data(mtcars)
> lm(as.matrix(mtcars[1:3]) ~ vs, data = mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = as.matrix(mtcars[1:3]) ~ vs, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
             mpg       cyl       disp    
(Intercept)    16.617     7.444   307.150
vs              7.940    -2.873  -174.693
```